# Eclipse won't load my javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javadoc

I'm trying to create a SWT application in eclipse. I've followed the instructions and loaded the org.eclipse.swt project to my workspace, and made it a dependency of my project by adding it to my build path.

However i cannot see the javadoc when i'm referencing the SWT libraries. I tried extracting the 'src.zip' into the org.eclipse.swt project, and then tried generating the Javadoc which created a 'doc' folder with a whole bunch of html files, so i think it's all there, it's just that eclipse isn't picking it up.

Can someone suggest anything please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to generate anything to get the Javadoc.

See if you can edit your SWT build classpath entry and attach the src.zip there. That should be enough to display the associated javadoc (like in [this tutorial](http://www.iandickinson.me.uk/articles/jena-eclipse-helloworld/), except you can reference an external file `src.zip` instead of the external '`src`' directory).

Comment: In the end, i ended up doing something similar to this and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to extract the zip or generate the Javadoc. I assume you followed the instructions listed here:

[Developing SWT applications using Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php)

I followed the same steps and was able to view the Javadocs in the Javadoc view tab. The tab is automatically updated whenever you click on a class you are instantiating in your code.